# How to extend existing token expire time for Laravel JWT

Tags: laravel, jwt, token

I already have issued a lot of token for an existing application on production. There was a `ttl` and `refresh_ttl` value in JWT config. I have set `ttl` and `refresh_ttl` to `null` so that the new tokens doesn't have an expiration time. Right now, I want to remove expiration time from all the existing tokens. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Actually, if you don't care about token expiry, you can just opt to have your Laravel code completely _ignore_ the `exp` claim in the incoming token.  You could also remove expiry from the claims, but you don't have to.

Comment: *remove expiration time from all the existing tokens* - you can't change an existing token, you can only issue a new one. Either ignore the expiration as Tim suggested or invalidate all existing tokens (by changing the key) and reissue non expiring tokens. But if you have refresh tokens, why do you worry about the exp?

Comment: @jps Because the refresh token also have a time which was half of ttl. Now the refresh token does not work as well. If I increase the refresh token time, will it be able to refresh existing expired token?

Comment: yes, as long as the refresh token is valid, it can be used to reissue an access token. Usually a refresh token has a longer ttl than an access token, eg. 12h to 1h

Comment: Can you tell me if the refresh token ttl is also set when the token is generated or whenever it tries to refresh? If it's set when the token was created, then the existing tokens won't have any effect even if I change the refresh ttl time now